# Can i compare Object and String without parsing

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
Object investorLoanDB = dbData.get("investorLoanNo");
    

chipAssert.assertEquals(investorLoan.getText(), investorLoanDB);
```

investorLoan is WebElement type.

Comment: You can compare anything you like, but they probably won't be equal unless your object is actually a string.

Comment: The question is very much incomplete. What does getText() return? If string then you should also call inverstorLoanDB.getText() or some other method. But, your question is not leading me anywhere.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you feel the need to do that? It honestly doesn't take that much effort - just a line or two of code.